# fixed point inside parallaxe layers with css preserve-3d?

Tags: html, css

how i can add a fixed point inside a layers of this parallaxe demo.
https://codepen.io/djmisterjon/pen/LYXmLJV

I am looking for a way to place the bunny on the cliff.

But when resize document, bunny get the 3d effect and just move out the cliff.
Is it possible if knowing we use `transform-style: preserve-3d;` ?

- keyart-7-1 is the bunny here.

thanks

```html
<div class="page">
    <div class="keyart" id="parallax">
      <div class="keyart_layer" id="keyart-8"></div>
      <div class="keyart_layer" id="keyart-7"></div>
      
      <div class="keyart_layer" id="keyart-7-1"></div>
      
      <div class="keyart_layer" id="keyart-6"></div>
      <div class="keyart_layer" id="keyart-5"></div>
      <div class="keyart_layer" id="keyart-4"></div>
      <div class="keyart_layer" id="keyart-3"></div>
      <div class="keyart_layer" id="keyart-2"></div>
      <div class="keyart_layer" id="keyart-1"></div>
      <div class="keyart_layer" id="keyart-0"></div>
    </div>
  <div class="overflow">
    <h1>CSS Parallax - the bunny should fixed in #keyart-7</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family:Helvetica,Sans-serif;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
h1 {
  text-align:center;
}
.page {
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  perspective:1px;
  perspective-origin: center center;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
.overflow {
  position:absolute;
  width:100vw;
  height:80vh;
  top:100vh;
  background-color:#FFF;
}
#parallax {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  height:120vh;
}

.keyart_layer {
    background-position: bottom center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    position: absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
}

#keyart-0 {
  background-image: url('https://www.firewatchgame.com/images/parallax/parallax0.png');
  background-color: #ffaf1b;
  transform:translate3d(-11px,-46px,-1.3px) scale(2.3);
}
#keyart-1 {
  background-image: url('http://www.firewatchgame.com/images/parallax/parallax1.png');
  transform:translate3d(0,-47px,-.7px) scale(1.7);
}
#keyart-2 {
  background-image: url('http://www.firewatchgame.com/images/parallax/parallax2.png');
  transform:translate3d(0,-98px,-.4px) scale(1.6);
}
#keyart-3 {
  background-image: url('http://www.firewatchgame.com/images/parallax/parallax3.png');
  transform:translate3d(0,-2px,-.1px) scale(1.1);
}
#keyart-4 {
  background-image: url('http://www.firewatchgame.com/images/parallax/parallax4.png');
  transform:translate3d(0,35px,.1px) scale(.9);
}
#keyart-5 {
  background-image: url('http://www.firewatchgame.com/images/parallax/parallax5.png');
  transform:translate3d(0,84px,.2px) scale(.8);
}
#keyart-6 {
  background-image: url('http://www.firewatchgame.com/images/parallax/parallax6.png');
  transform:translate3d(0, 106px,.3px) scale(.7);
}
#keyart-7 {
  background-image: url('http://www.firewatchgame.com/images/parallax/parallax7.png');
  transform:translate3d(0,106px,.38px) scale(.65);
}
#keyart-7-1 {
  background-image: url('https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/f4468d92-e9bd-4f1f-a652-90387db1e84f/d7yzs9d-c93f9d98-49be-4a58-8ae3-e9e3170e7c23.png/v1/fill/w_1024,h_1071/vector__bunny_2_by_estories_d7yzs9d-fullview.png?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwiaXNzIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsIm9iaiI6W1t7ImhlaWdodCI6Ijw9MTA3MSIsInBhdGgiOiJcL2ZcL2Y0NDY4ZDkyLWU5YmQtNGYxZi1hNjUyLTkwMzg3ZGIxZTg0ZlwvZDd5enM5ZC1jOTNmOWQ5OC00OWJlLTRhNTgtOGFlMy1lOWUzMTcwZTdjMjMucG5nIiwid2lkdGgiOiI8PTEwMjQifV1dLCJhdWQiOlsidXJuOnNlcnZpY2U6aW1hZ2Uub3BlcmF0aW9ucyJdfQ.7S-XBWFBkj8KDhi-KQUP8X-qIENqqeQyO4qkGUk4GvY');
  transform:translate3d(-400px,-40px,0px) scale(.1);
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#keyart-8 {
  background-image: url('https://www.firewatchgame.com/images/parallax/parallax8.png');
  transform:translate3d(0, 180px,.45px) scale(.8);
}
```